# Raspberry Pi GPIO Signal Crosstalk

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

I am building a system which uses a **remote** attached to the **RPi** with a ribbon cable from about 3ft away.

- The remote has buttons on it which connect the Raspberry Pi's
  **GPIOs** to **GND**.The system works beautifully when I use a breakout board, plugging the ribbon cable into that.
- However, when I tried to connect the ribbon straight to the RPi,
  pressing 1 button often triggers 2 others.

  Why would this happen only at the RPi, but never at the breakout board? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Before I could preview the schemtaic circuit of the breakout board. I doubt it is caused by the drive capability of the pi board,you can mesure and compare the voltage on the button end between using breakout board and without it, it's really a hardware  issue and only way to solve is to check the schematic circuit and measure.  by the way, the question you asked is off-topic here.

Comment: My apologies. Where would this be on topic? The breakout board has no real circuitry, it's this product from adafruit. https://www.adafruit.com/product/2028

Comment: The breakout board shows on the web looks really simple,So it's ok without  circuit.  There are two different voltage outputs(3.3V and 5V) on the board , there are two possible different I thought. 1 voltage   2 ground connection.  check it please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Could you please elaborate? Also, I have more information. My circuit stops triggering multiple inputs if I hold the back of the board (i.e. Short the switch contacts with my finger). I tested it extensively, and it works every single time. So the question is, is it the resistance or capacitance of my hand that is doing the trick. Thoughts?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot to show what I plan to make for the pullup circuits. I've got 1k protection resistors (it seems like that is usually good form) and 5k1 current resistors. The green wires would go to separate GPIO pins and the red and black connect to 3v3 and gnd respectively. Does this seem sound? http://imgur.com/a/WQSu3

Comment: After check your button board I thought the malfunction is caused by floated GPIO, The GPIO can't function normally as an input if it is not be pulled up/down rightly, you can use software to enable internal pull up/down(simple way) , for example:  
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

Comment: you can also use external resistors to do these work(a little trouble then the first one). 
for example: GND-->switch--->gpio  
                                              |-->10k resistor-->VCC(pull up) .
                           VCC--→switch---→gpio
                                                      |-→10k resistor-→GND(pull down)
  don't mix use these two methods together.

Comment: When you touch the button board using your finger, it virtually simulate  a resistor to connect vcc or gnd to the gpio, which make floated GPIO happy when neither software nor hardware set pull up/down  for it.